Filling array with primes is suspiciously slow - am I missing something?
I'm doing basic exercise of building list of primes using trial division in Julia (just starting to learn the language) and noticed it is much slower than expected - I guess it is not an issue with the language but rather I miss something - so am asking for review and advice.
Initial attempt was this:
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7]

function isprime(x)
    global primes
    for d in primes
        if d * d > x return true end
        if x % d == 0 return false end
    end
end

n = 100000
p = 9
while true
    if isprime(p)
        append!(primes, p)
        if size(primes, 1) == n
            println("primes[$n] = $(primes[n])")
            break
        end
    end
    global p += 2
end

This takes about 3 seconds on my meek laptop for n = 100000 and if I change n = 1000000 I have no patience to wait for end of execution.
It should be much faster because:

I made sure that loops without arrays are as fast as in natively-compiled languages (I had written previous exercise on counting collatz sequence steps for million integers - it works under 1 second)
similarly structured code in Lua is faster (e.g. 2 seconds) despite being slow interpreted language (without LuaJit)

I tried to make array preallocated, but it didn't help much. Then I tried replacing for over a range inside a function with simple while:
function isprime(x)
    global primes
    i = 1
    while true
        d = primes[i]
        i += 1
        if d * d > x return true end
        if x % d == 0 return false end
    end
end

(full code, with preallocated array)
It helped a bit (say, 2 seconds now instead of 3) but still I obviously miss some main source of inefficiency.

Julia dislikes global variables, especially global array that are manipulated as yours are. Just declaring primes const gives a 20X speedup, which you can also get by simply wrapping all of your code in a let ... end block and removing the global declarations.

Read https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/ In particular, avoid global variables, and put your code in functions (no loops in global scope).

@Bill and DNF - thank you both, and for the link also. Definitely it was the issue I was looking for . Refactored the code according to your suggestion and added as an answer.

Many thanks to Bill and DNF who answered in comments - I checked and they are quite right, it is just about array of primes being global. Here comes small refactoring with wrapping main code into function and passing array as an argument to isprime - this fixes performance to the value competing with natively-compiled code (i.e. even for 1 mln calculation takes about 2 seconds at the same hardware as used above):
function isprime(primes, x)
    for d in primes
        if d * d > x return true end
        if x % d == 0 return false end
    end
end

function main()
    primes = [2, 3, 5, 7]
    n = parse(Int64, ENV["MAXN"])
    p = 9
    while true
        if isprime(primes, p)
            append!(primes, p)
            if size(primes, 1) == n
                println("primes[$n] = $(primes[n])")
                break
            end
        end
        p += 2
    end
end

main()


There are still performance issues with this code. isprime isn't type stable since it isn't guaranteed to return anything. And main iteratively expands a vector, which is slow. Do you even need the entire vector, or only the last element?

these are true but their effect is negligible compared to the main issue you pointed first :) especially about expanding array vs preallocating I hardly found any difference in running time here (which could be explained by the fact that we actually do not expand on every iteration and there is enough work happening besides)
